# Find the function name and parameter from input data

Tags: web3js

Transaction hash give input data like this
"0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000024c38db6c4a85b3e6b58631de2334105f6209da300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dca4f1516a8".
if i call this function
let encodedFunctionSignature = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature('transfer(address,uint256)');

it give me this "0xa9059cbb".etherscan call this methodId

My question is how i get the transfer(address,uint256)  back from this "0xa9059cbb"

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function selector is the first four bytes of the keccak256 hash of the canonicalized function signature. In this case, `web3.sha3('transfer(address,uint256)').substring(0, 10) === "0xa9059cbb"`.

Reversing this process is not generally possible unless the contract's code or ABI is provided. That said, as long as someone else has used a given function selector before and provided its original name, you can use that information instead.

One list of commonly used function selectors is here: https://github.com/ethereum-lists/4bytes, and in fact `transfer(addresss,uint256)` is the first example given.

Comment: Can you identify with the input data that the given transaction hash involve token transfer or not?

Comment: No, that's never strictly possible. (I could write a contract with a function `transfer(address,uint256)` that did nothing.)

Comment: So if i am making a explorer like etherscan, I can't get token transfer information between two address without contract ABI?Right?